# Extracting a region's outline of roads from a GIS database, as a vector image

Tags: shapefile, export, vector-tiles, svg, transportation

It's now about 5 days I've been trying to extract an outline of the internal transportation routes of a city (Tehran) from various kinds of GIS sources, and exporting that outline as a vector image, preferrably as an SVG.

To that end, I have tried using QGIS for opening the tileset in https://openmaptiles.com/downloads/dataset/osm/asia/iran/tehran/#8.91/35.102/51.0771 and every single GIS file at https://download.bbbike.org/osm/bbbike/Tehran/ . I have ransacked the Internet for help, but so far I've been totally clueless as to where to even begin.

I have attached the result I'm trying to achieve at the end of this post.
[image: the route outline of teheran]

Comment: Part of your problem comes from the way you've named the task -- "vector image". Vector GIS datasets are very different from raster images.  If you want a vector, you should try to obtain that; and the same with rasters.  SVG isn't really a GIS format -- It's more of an IT/Graphics thing.

Answer (score 1):

You are going about it the hard way, it is much easier to start with the vector data and convert that to SVG.

So to get Iran data from Open Street Map the easy way is to go to [GeoFabrik's download server page for Iran](https://download.geofabrik.de/asia/iran.html) and fetch the [shapefiles](https://download.geofabrik.de/asia/iran-latest-free.shp.zip). Then drag that file into QGIS, select just gis_osm_roads_free_1.shp (for now anyway).

[image]

Then zoom into Tehran (your colour may be different here, don't worry).

[image]

You can then [create a Print Layout](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/training_manual/map_composer/map_composer.html) (4th Icon from the left, piece of paper with a yellow star),

Then drag out a map view (7th icon down) and [export as SVG](https://docs.qgis.org/3.16/en/docs/user_manual/print_composer/create_output.html) (another piece of paper with a star on it).

From what I can see this seems to create a suitable vector SVG file - at least I can open it in inkscape and select roads (which is about my limit it inkscape).

[image]